# Is Blender appropriate for learning Stereometry (a subject in mathematics)?

Tags: geometry, mathematics, vector

In some countries, senior high school students are still taught about Sterometry in which we are asked to draw a cross section between a solid and a plane, for example, as follows.

Shortly speaking, is Blender appropriate to use here? I am relatively new to Blender and I have not found the tools to

- attach mathematics symbols such as omega, theta, etc.
- create points that are geometrically constrained such as AB:AC= 2:3, etc.
- find intersecting points, etc

[image]

Comment: I think you can do many things: intersections, constrained objects, etc. About math symbol you can use the font you want inside Blender. You can also see lengths, angles, surfaces, etc. But I won't pretend to know stereometry so won't answer more than that.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a job for Geogebra, not Blender

Comment: I don't think so, any analysis you do with Blender is going to be done in the console via Python code and you would need to build it yourself (unless you want to do that anyway), whereas you will get realtime visual feedback with Geogebra. That is the tool I would use

Comment: It would be insightful if you explained you use-case... is this for you or a project you want to do for secondary school students?

Comment: I don't understand, could you update your question with the precise goal of your project? Because you mentioned high school and math problems a lot in your question but now it sounds like you are trying to improve something in a project you are working on? Please clarify EDIT: OH...I would not recommend trying to annotate within Blender because it will be a slow process but if Geogebra can't get you the shape you need, I would annotate a screenshot in any other program

Comment: Alright, good luck, pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the image you attached I'd say it's, but to an extent. I mean you can model in B3D the solid shown and make it transparent. Use Shear for the cross-section, render it. Still, for all those **lines** an external image editor is the fastest way.

[image]